# Document/Image Database Repository Design Question

Tags: sql-server, middleware, document-imaging

Question:

Should I write my application to directly access a database Image Repository or write a middleware piece to handle document requests.

Background:

I have a custom Document Imaging and Workflow application that currently stores about 15 million documents/document images (90%+ single page, group 4 tiffs, the rest PDF, Word and Excel documents).  The image repository is a commercial, 3rd party application that is very expensive and frankly has too much overhead.  I just need a system to store and retrieve document images.

I'm considering moving the imaging directly into a SQL Server 2005 database.  The indexing information is very limited - basically 2 index fields.  It's a life insurance policy administration system so I index images with a policy number and a system wide unique id number.  There are other index values, but they're stored and maintained separately from the image data.  Those index values give me the ability to look-up the unique id value for individual image retrieval.

The database server is a dual-quad core windows 2003 box with SAN drives hosting the DB files.  The current image repository size is about 650GB. I haven't done any testing to see how large the converted database will be.  I'm not really asking about the database design - I'm working with our DBAs on that aspect.  If that changes, I'll be back :-)

The current system to be replaced is obviously a middleware application, but it's a very heavyweight system spread across 3 windows servers.  If I go this route, it would be a single server system.

My primary concerns are scalabity and performace - heavily weighted toward performance.  I have about 100 users, and usage growth will probably be slow for the next few years.
Most users are primarily read users - they don't add images to the system very often.  We have a department that handles scanning and otherwise adding images to the repository.  We also have a few other applications that receive documents (via ftp) and they insert them into the repository automatically as they are received, either will full index information or as "batches" that a user reviews and indexes.

Most (90%+) of the documents/images are very small, < 100K, probably < 50K, so I believe that storage of the images in the database file will be the most efficient rather than getting SQL 2008 and using a filestream.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oftentimes scalability and performance are ultimately married to each other in the sense that six months from now management comes back and says "Function Y in Application X is running unacceptably slow, how do we speed it up?" And all too the often the answer is to upgrade the back end solution. And when it comes to upgrading back ends, its almost always going to less expensive to scale out than to scale up in terms of hardware.

So, long story short, I would recommend building a middleware app that specifically handles incoming requests from the user app and then routes them to the appropriate destination. This will sufficiently abstract your front-end user app from the back end storage solution so that when scalability does become an issue only the middleware app will need to be updated.

Answer (score 2):

This is straightforward. Write the application to an interface, use some kind of factory mechanism to supply that interface, and implement that interface however you want.

Once you're happy with your interface, then the application is (mostly) isolated from the implementation, whether it's talking straight to a DB or to some other component.

Thinking ahead a bit on your interface design but doing bone stupid, "it's simple, it works here, it works now" implementations offers a good balance of future proofing the system while not necessarily over engineering it.

It's easy to argue you don't even need an interface at this juncture, rather just a simple class that you instantiate. But if your contract is well defined (i.e. the interface or class signature), that is what protects you from change (such as redoing the back end implementation). You can always replace the class with an interface later if you find it necessary.

As far as scalability, test it. Then you know not only if you may need to scale, but perhaps when as well. "Works great for 100 users, problematic for 200, if we hit 150 we might want to consider taking another look at the back end, but it's good for now."

That's due diligence and a responsible design tactic, IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with gabriel1836. However, an added benefit would be that you could for a time run a hybrid system for a time since you aren't going to convert 14 millions documents from your proprietary system to you home grown system overnight.

Also, I would strongly encourage you to store the documents outside of a database. Store them on a file system (local, SAN, NAS it doesn't matter) and store pointers to the documents in the database.

I'd love to know what document management system you are using now.

Also, don't underestimate the effort of replacing the capture (scanning and importing) provided by the proprietary system.

Comment: It's currently running on Optika's Acorde (which was acquired by Stellent, and then acquired by Oracle).  Capture isn't an issue, as we purchased the Kofax image controls toolkit and wrote our own scanning application.

Comment: Ahhh, I feel for you. Acorde is not the greatest piece of software around. I used it's predecessor (FilePower) and it sucked also.